# Store large bitmap into memory or constantly decode smaller bitmaps

Tags: java, android, bitmap

> **(if you want to skip all this text you can go straight to the "short
>   question" version at the bottom)**

Hello, guys!

I'm a beginner android developer currently creating a 2D RPG game. It basically consists of a map where the player walks (in 8 possible directions - west, north-west, and so forth) and interact with objects, creatures and others. The player's character walking animation consists of 9 sprites per available walking direction, totalizing 72 sprites. I have these sprites both in individual .png files as well as in an organized sprite sheet.

Until some days ago, I've been using the individual sprites in the game. I would load their drawable ID into an `int[][]` array and then, when each frame was going to be drawn, I would decode (using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` method) the necessary sprite and pass it to my renderer class that would then draw it.

After some thinking, I decided to try and use the sprite sheet instead, since the constant decoding of the sprites images was bothering me. For that, I decode the bitmap containing the sprite sheet with all the needed sprites and store it into a member variable. Depending on the required sprite for the next frame, my program would crop the required sprite out of the sprite sheet (previously saved into memory), resize it according to the player's devices needs and then pass it to my renderer in order to be drawn.

The problem is, I can't tell which method is more efficient! While it's easy to measure how much memory the decoded sprite sheet bitmap occupies (when stored in a member variable) in the player's memory (approximately 4MB), it's hard to know how much memory my program uses for constantly decoding small bitmaps, that corresponds to the individual sprites. Does anyone have any insights on how I could make this comparison? Or perhaps can share a previous experience related to this subject? I have searched for hours and, despite having found much useful information on how to load bitmaps efficiently and suggestions for libraries (like Glide, Fresco, and Picasso), I still couldn't find an answer nor better methods. Thanks in advance!

**SHORT QUESTION:** Is it better to constantly decode small bitmaps or to just decode a large bitmap once and then crop smaller bitmaps from it as needed?

**P.S.:** I'm aware that both presented methods for creating the animations in my game are probably inefficient. But, for the sake of my learning (my primary objective for creating this game), I don't want to use game engines, like AndEngine and libgdx. I also started learning OpenGL ES (which I've read provides great tools for loading and displaying bitmaps), but implementing it into my game would require a complete remake, in which I'm not interested right now.

Comment: Cropping bitmaps from an in-memory bitmap will be more efficient.  But it may use more memory.  Take your pick.  But don't take my word for it.  Write some code to try it out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As a matter of fact I did write code for both methods, the problem is I don't know how to measure the efficiency of decoding small bitmaps on the fly in order to compare it with the memory usage of loading a large bitmap into the memory.

Comment: There are standard frameworks (e.g. jmh) for implementing Java benchmarks.  There are standard tools (called profilers) for measuring what proportion of time that an application spends in a particular part of the code.  I suggest you research these topics ... then implement your own benchmarks / do your own profiling.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could actually check the time spent on a defined part of the code! Thank you, I will try it with Android Studio's profiler.